# laravel redirect to correct page after destroying but with different url

Tags: laravel

I have an Item controller where I call the `destroy` function when I hit the submit button.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    items::destroy($id);

    return redirect()->route('items.index');
}
```

This is the corresponding method for the route named `items.index`:

```
public function index()
{
    $items = items::orderBy('category','asc')
        ->orderBy('partnumber','asc')
        ->get();

    return view('items.index')->with('items', $items);
}
```

I am redirected to this index view but the url remains the same. Can anyone explain to me why the URL is not changing?

Here is a screen shot:

[image: screenshot after destroying an item]]

Comment: Try Redirect::route('items');

Comment: or just return redirect('items'); will work

Comment: Hi its still not working. :(